# Why does element selector beat class selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I expect font-size: 20px for the li elements

html and css here
https://jsfiddle.net/15m9tsq6/

```
div {
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  color: #2c3e49;
  font-size: 12px;
} 

.kk-wrapper {
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Oxygen-Sans,Ubuntu,Cantarell,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
}
```

[image]

Comment: use `*` to select all elements in this class `.kk-wrapper * {}` :https://jsfiddle.net/Lg2k4tqd/

Comment: As you can see, https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZhMQ.png the `.kk-wrapper` class was applied to the li element, so I suppose `*` is not needed

Comment: the answer: inheritance